# Reproducing org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend

Tags: postgresql, psql

For testing purposes, I need to reproduce *An I/O error occured while sending to the backend* error.

My application is facing problems after this error and I need to test why is that.

I know that this is some kind of network problem, but I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: You need to break the network socket abruptly. Introduce a firewall rule that sends a TCP `RST` when the client tries to transmit a packet. Add some code within the client that sneakily closes the underlying socket without telling the upper layers it did so. That sort of thing. Hard to be specific since you haven't given any specifics to refer to - like the client language/library, operating system, Pg version, etc.

Comment: I am working with postgresql 9.2 on Gentoo Linux 3.12.21.
I would be best for me if I could block IP address via Shorewall. I tried trough blacklist but it does not work

Comment: Just use a local iptables rule.